# Real value of Google Ads app conversion rates

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, conversions

We are facing a doubt when reading the technical details of the products and steps needed for publicizing our app and then measuring the app conversion rate as an effect of the paid campaigns.

We are planning to use Google Ads, and it claims to offer mechanisms for collecting download metrics and the ability to record a wide range of events inside the app so you can get the user conversion rate datum.

Our doubt is about what happens inside the barrier between the click on the add and the first app start? Is Google really able to assure you that a single click on the add leaded to a real app install, or does the tool just show you a click count and an install/start count? - so it's up to you to conclude the click leaded to the install.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far my workmate, who is in CPA, explained it to me - it depends.
There are two kinds of Adwords campaigns for apps - installation and reactivation/usage. If you run installation campaign - Google would recognize the installation, if you run reactivation/usage campaign - Google would recognize app start.

Comment: Hmmm thank you, I hadn't that info and it's useful, anyway it doesn't answer the question about Google being really able to link the click -> install data (or click -> usage) or the linking is simply artificial. If we promote app install on several platforms, then it may be impossible to relate the app install/usage events to the clicks on every campaign.